# How to recreate this synth sound?

Tags: synthesizer

This is most likely extremelly basic, but how would I go about trying to recreate this synth sound here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty close to the original sound.

https://clyp.it/5ii2snn0

I used NI Massive for the synth. Pretty basic saw patch with some detune and automation. Also used a free bitcrusher plugin and some basic EQ/saturation. I can give you the patch if you have Massive.

Answer (score 1):

there's definitely aliasing artifacts in there but I am not sure whether that was caused by the encoding to youtube or whether that was part of the original sound. Sounds like a fairly stock standard synth sound to me - going to be trial and error just hunting around for it, but the resampling artifacts can probably be introduced by a decimator plugin of some variety.